# Type conversion issues when LINQ projecting into ADO.Net Entity Framework class

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm running into some issues when constructing a query using LINQ and Entity Framework.

My model is like this

```
Merchants(MerchantId)
    AffiliateFeeds(AffiliateFeedId, MerchantId)
        ProductSKUs(ProductId, AffiliateFeedId)
```

This snippet works well enough:

```
// only get Merchants and AffiliateFeeds based on specific ProductSKU.ProductId

var productSKUs = from ps in _context.ProductSKUs
                    where ps.ProductId == 38
                    select ps.AffiliateFeedId;

var feeds = from af in _context.AffiliateFeeds
            where productSKUs.Contains(af.AffiliateFeedId)
            select af;

var dm = (from f in feeds select f.MerchantId).Distinct();   

var merchants = from m in _context.Merchants
                where dm.Contains(m.MerchantId)
                select new 
                {
                    MerchantId = m.MerchantId,
                    Name = m.Name,
                    SysName = m.SysName,
                    DataFeedUrl = m.DataFeedUrl,
                    AffiliateFeeds = feeds.Where(x => x.MerchantId == m.MerchantId)
                };
```

However when I try and perform the projection into an Entity Framework generated class called Merchant as so:

```
var merchants = from m in _context.Merchants
                where dm.Contains(m.MerchantId)
                select new Merchant
                {
                    MerchantId = m.MerchantId,
                    Name = m.Name,
                    SysName = m.SysName,
                    DataFeedUrl = m.DataFeedUrl,
                    AffiliateFeeds = feeds.Where(x => x.MerchantId == m.MerchantId)
                };
```

I get an error stating:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error message itself is fairly clear: the property `AffiliateFeeds` is of type `EntityCollection<SACore.AffiliateFeed>` and you're trying to assign an arbitrary `IQueryable<SACore.AffiliateFeed>` to it.

Quite how to *fix* the problem is a different matter. I would expect that `Where` clause to effectively be automatic based on the entity definitions for the join between the tables.

Comment: Thanks :D I'm trying to iterate thru a list of Merchants and then iterate thru the associated AffiliateFeeds. If I do not project, when I iterate thre the feeds, the entire list of feeds is shown. It's like the constraints I applied were ignored. Would you know why this is?

Comment: @sf: I don't have much experience of EF, but basically check the AffiliateFeeds/Merchant relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't project onto EF types. You can project onto POCOs and anonymous types, but not onto EF-mapped types. The reason is that the EF will never partially materialize an instance of an entity.